# RobotFramework: troubles typing some fields

Tags: python, automated-tests, robotframework, python-appium

How can I type numbers using an Android keyboard instead of using the Input Text  "Field"?

I'm expecting that it's possible to simulate keyboard pressing.

Asking this because I've had some trouble sending values with the Input Text command inside an EditText.